# Ruby on Rails - param is missing or the value is empty

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm looking for some help with my rails app :

I have an error when i'm trying to create an estimate on a based landmark, below my controller

```
def create
  @landmark = Landmark.find(params[:landmark_id])
  @estimate = Estimate.new(estimate_params)
  @estimate.landmark = @landmark
  @estimate.price = @landmark.price
  if @estimate.save
    # Deliver the signup email
    NotificationMailer.create_project(@estimate).deliver
    redirect_to landmark_path(@landmark, :notice => 'Booking created')
  else
    redirect_to landmark_path(@landmark, :notice => 'Error during creation')
  end
end
```

with my param :

```
def estimate_params
  params.require(:estimate).permit(:price)
end
```

I dont understand why my param price is missing.

> param is missing or the value is empty: estimate

Thank in advance for your help

Comment: What does your form look like?

Comment: Looking at the error there is a high possibility hat your form is incorrect. Check e.g. in your browser networking that in the request that is fired the price param is wrapped inside the estimate param. Like this: `estimate[price]=1234` .

Comment: Sorry for the late answer and thanks @ErwinSchens that was helpfull my form was wrong.